# Low quality posts can be accessed without 2k rep

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, privileges, low-quality-posts

The review page for users with less than 2k reputation claims that:

> You need at least 2k reputation to review Low Quality Posts.

However, any user, including one with less than the required reputation amount can view these by simply opening one of the First Answers, First Questions, or Late Answers tabs, then by clicking on Low Quality Posts. This is completely visible and accessible by users of any reputation level.

Comment: This is a bit stupid, considering that even low rep users can suggest edit.

Comment: @nhahtdh given the review system tends to encourage a high quantity of edits (and other activity) I think it makes sense to delay access until after full edit has been gained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by-design.  In the new system you need at least 2k reputation (edit) to review low quality posts.  Below 2k, you can't do much that's meaningful except push work into someone else's queue by suggesting an edit or recommending delete / close.

The workaround of going to the old page will be removed once we get rid of the old page.